# How to use dynamic xpath in tosca

Tags: tosca

I have a scenario where I have to use xpath to identify the  element . However I want the xpath to be dynamic and the parameter that I pass to xpath should be based on buffer that I stored as part of the test run.

Is it possible to give buffer value in xpath ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You must put the buffer name in quotes. Here how I use it to iterate over `Number` for `div[Number]`:

```
"id('table')/div["{B[Number]}"]"
                 ^-----------^ < note the quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with *{B[your_buffer_name]}* within your xpath? I never tried using a buffer in a property but that may work.

I would also suggest finding other ways of uniquely identifying your elements. IMHO xpath is rather prone to being unstable. Any change in the page structure will likely break it.

Comment: Results in error such as "The XPath-expression 'id('chrome-table')/div[{B[Number]}]/span[1]' could not be evaluated!" This syntax works in inner text or outer text etc but not in xpath which is quite strange.

Comment: I see :( and are you absolutely sure that you need am xpath in this case? maybe you can solve it with an anchor or with an "ExplicitName" attribute?

Comment: It was not my question but I faced the same problem. I need to go through a column in a table (which is not a table in html-terms) and xpath seems to be the easiest way to do it (just iterate over div[n] in my example above). And tosca cant do it.

Comment: sorry, had not seen that you had posted an answer :) good job on finding the solution!